Is the cup used to drink from the pool in the House of Black and White made from a human skull?
In the Game of Thrones episode High Sparrow (S05E03), when someone comes to the House of Black and White to end their lives, they drink from the pool of poisoned water, drawing water from the pool with a cup that looks like it was the top of someone's skull.



Is that really the case, or am I just imagining it?

I found the clip on Youtube showing the scene. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HS2uO17lqNA&t=244s Looking at the "cup" it appears to be to round to be a skull (a skull would probably be to oval or egg shaped) It is also small, if it was a skull it would be of a small child or baby. The rim is also to thick to be the skull of a baby or child. It also appears the upper rim is slightly curved inward. To me, other than the white interior, it looks nothing like a skull.

The cup that is visible very clearly at 4:11 in the linked video doesn't look like a skull at all, it looks more like half a coconut. Much too small to be a skull. Perhaps you are thinking of some other scene.
